# Retrieve distinct SQL query results for one column and not the other column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that has the following format for the data.  All I want is just one code and phone number.  It does not matter which phone number I get, all I need it one phone number.

- Code phoneNumber
- 1000009  (123)752-0108
- 1000257  (456)718-1229
- 1000257  (789)750-1057
- 1000259  (000)000-0001 1000259   (111)453-0522
  1000259 (222)460-8947 1000270   (333)528-6468 1000276   (444)384-5571

The results I need would look like:
Code    phoneNumber
1000009 (123)752-0108
1000257 (456)718-1229
1000259 (000)000-0001
1000270 (333)528-6468
1000276 (444)384-5571

Any help with the SQL query would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the phoneNumbers for a given code is sufficient, you can use a [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) with any of the [aggregating functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) to accomplish just that

This example uses the `MAX` aggregating function.

```
SELECT  Code
        , PhoneNumber = MAX(phoneNumber)
FROM    Table
GROUP BY
        Code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SLEECT Code, phoneNumber,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY phoneNumber) AS RowNum
        FROM YourTable
)
SELECT Code, phoneNumber
    FROM cteRowNum
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```